# Systemd service file doesn't read the environmentFile

Tags: linux, systemd, etcd

I am trying to start `etcd` service and I have a environment variable file that I am referring by the `systemd` file.

First time it works fine and in the next time when I try to **stop** the service and do the same steps, it doesn't read the `environmentFile` and update the values.

Here's my `/etc/etcd.conf` where I put environment variables

```
INTERNAL_IP=$(ip -o route get to 8.8.8.8 | sed -n 's/.*src \([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/p')

cat << EOF > /etc/etcd.conf
#SELF_IP is the IP of the node where this file resides.
SELF_IP=$INTERNAL_IP
# IP of Node 1
NODE_1_IP=10.128.15.225
#IP of Node 2
NODE_2_IP=10.128.15.226
NODE_3_IP=10.128.15.227
EOF
```

This is my `/etc/systemd/system/etcd3.service` file

```
cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/system/etcd3.service
[Unit]
Description=etcd
Documentation=https://github.com/coreos/etcd
Conflicts=etcd.service
Conflicts=etcd2.service

[Service]
Type=notify
Restart=always
RestartSec=25s
LimitNOFILE=40000
TimeoutStartSec=1s
EnvironmentFile=/etc/etcd.conf
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/local/bin/etcd --name etcd-${SELF_IP} --data-dir /var/lib/etcd --quota-backend-bytes 8589934592 --auto-compaction-retention 3 --listen-client-urls http://${SELF_IP}:2379,http://localhost:2379 --advertise-client-urls http://${SELF_IP}:2379,http://localhost:2379 --listen-peer-urls http://${SELF_IP}:2380 --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://${SELF_IP}:2380 --initial-cluster 'etcd-${NODE_1_IP}=http://${NODE_1_IP}:2380,etcd-${NODE_2_IP}=http://${NODE_2_IP}:2380,etcd-${NODE_3_IP}=http://${NODE_3_IP}:2380' --initial-cluster-token my-etcd-token --initial-cluster-state new"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

Why this is working for the first time and not afterwards?

**How can i stop the service successfully and try to create the `/etc/etcd.conf` with some additional values and start the same service**

because it gives the below error:

```
-- Subject: Unit etcd3.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit etcd3.service has begun starting up.
Nov 19 15:08:59 etcd-1 etcd[2341]: error verifying flags, expected IP in URL for binding (http://:2380). See 'etcd --help'.
Nov 19 15:08:59 etcd-1 systemd[1]: etcd3.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 19 15:08:59 etcd-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start etcd.
-- Subject: Unit etcd3.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit etcd3.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

and when I try to cat `/etc/systemd/system/etcd3.service` after the first time (i.e second time after executing the same commands), the values I have passed are not really shown their, instead it shows empty values, such as `--name etcd-`

Comment: `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/local/bin/etcd` Wouldn't it be simpler to just write that line in a script file? What the point of "EnvironmentFile" then a super long ilne. Just have one script.

Comment: What do you suggest @KamilCuk

Comment: I suspect the value of `SELF_IP` is empty because `$INTERNAL_IP` is unset. Where is `SELF_IP=$INTERNAL_IP` set?

Comment: No, it is set, but I didn't mention that line here. when I `echo $INTERNAL_IP` it prints the value. Not just that all other values are also empty.

Comment: `when I echo $INTERNAL_IP`? _where_ do you "echo" that value? From _within_ the systemd script?

Comment: no, just in the terminal. Can you give me a better way to structure these scripts? I added INTERNAL_IP for better understanding

Comment: `in the terminal` so the process started by systemd is not aware of _any_ operations you are doing _in your terminal_. These are separate processes. With separate variables.

Comment: I updated the answer can you have a look now?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with the shell variables like `${SELF_IP}` in the `ExecStart=` line.
One is that

```sh
cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/system/etcd3.service
```

does variable interpolation, so the `etcd3.service` file will replace `${SELF_IP}` by whatever its current value is, perhaps empty. The fix for this is to quote the `EOF` as in `cat <<'EOF'` for example.

The next problem will then be that systemd also interpolates variables of the form `${...}` in the `ExecStart=` line, even when inside single or double quotes. So they will again be replaced by the current value for systemd (which uses the `EnvironmentFile` when running the command, not when parsing the line), so probably empty.

The fix for this is to double the `$` signs on this line, eg `$${SELF_IP}`. If you use `/bin/bash -cv` as the command you should be able to see what command is passed to bash, and whether the variables have survived that far.

Comment: Should I also include single quotations for `EOF` after the end of `/etc/systemd/system/etcd3.service`  or is it only for the first occurrence of `EOF`

Comment: No, it is only for `<<'EOF'`, with `EOF` at the end as before.

Comment: Can you update the answer with the final changes? So I can see if I did it right?